# Prototyping "arguments"

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, mootools

**Introduction**

We all know these silly `arguments` objects of JavaScript functions.

> But why object? Isn't it an array?

No, it's not and that's why a lot people call it a failure in JavaScripts concept:

```
(function () {
    return arguments.slice(); // TypeError: arguments.slice is not a function
}());
```

---

**Intention**

Okay, that's just an introduction to the real thing I'd like to ask, but before asking you need some more information:

While reading different code during the last days, I got quite scarry while seeing the following line of code in quite a lot places.

```
args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments);
```

So, what does it do, is simply "converting" the `arguments` object into an array with all of its prototypes and stuff.

---

**My solution**

What I thought of was the following: While JavaScript is all about prototyping, why don't we extend the `arguments` object's `prototype` itself? I checked some sites for existing scripts, but found nothing I was intended to find and finally got to write it myself:

```
(function () {
    var i, methods;

    arguments.constructor.prototype = Array.prototype;
    methods = ['concat', 'join', 'pop', 'push', 'reverse', 'shift', 'slice', 'sort', 'splice', 'toString', 'unshift'];

    for (i = 0; i < methods.length; i += 1) {
        if (arguments.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty(methods[i]) === false) {
            arguments.constructor.prototype[methods[i]] = Array.prototype[methods[i]];
        }
    }
}());
```

After compression it takes 260 byte only and extends the `arguments` object's `prototype` by using `Array.prototype`.

So finally I can handle `arguments` objects just the same way as "real" arrays.

---

**The question**

After checking the most famous JavaScript frameworks I finished with the following: none uses such a construct and extends the `arguments` object's `prototype`.

But why? Is there anything wrong with, I don't think of right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `arguments` object is not a type, it is a generic `Object`. In order to extend it's prototype, you would have to extend the prototype of `Object`, which is generally not a good idea.

There is nothing wrong with converting `arguments` to an Array using `Array.prototype.slice`.

Let's say I was to extend the `arguments` prototype:

```
arguments.constructor.prototype.foo = 'bar';
```

The problem here is that `arguments.constructor` is not some `Argument` object, it's just `Object`. Now if I try to do something that should work normally, it's fubar'd:

```
var someNewObject = {
    someProperty: 'someValue'
};

for (var item in someNewObject) {
    console.log(item);  // logs someProperty AND foo, not good
}
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JYpPS/).

Comment: Actually you're right, didn't notice that. That's exactly what I was looking for... Well, sometimes there's just something to forget to think about...

Comment: This is also one (in addition to performance) of the reasons why an iterative integer for loop is preferred over a for-in loop. While you can use the method .hasOwnProperty() within a for-in, it is generally unsafe to due to the potential of augmented native objects (especially the Array object).

Comment: @say2joe for-in loops are for objects, for loops are for everything else.

Comment: @jbabey Not sure why you posted that comment. I think its rather obvious by my statement that I know how to use loops, but, more importantly, your statement is quite misleading. An Array is an object... and, a for-in loop is not a best practice to iterate over an Array. If you meant, a for-in loop should only be used with a static object literal (for example, an object based on JSON data) then your comment makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, most people shy away from changing ECMAScript/JavaScript native objects. Personally, I like your approach (it is clever and useful); however, you introduce problems when you introduce your code into larger projects. There may be unintended consequences when a browser's implementation of the Array (native) object differs from standards and other code libraries (like jQuery) handles that with certain expectations. If however, jQuery expects an arguments property (/object) of a function to be of a certain type and it has been changed, for example by your code, you may very well break a widely-used library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work? ;-)

If so, I think you have achieved what you wanted. However, one reason of arguments not being an array might be that the arguments variable is not meant to travel around like a normal variable. It is meant to only be accessed within the function body and then trashed. I thus don't know what happens when it suddenly *is* an Array.

Other than that, clever solution!